# Is this possible to Set ViewController Storyboard ID programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

[image: please check this ss]

In ss we can set Storyboard id using Interface Builder but I don't want to use this so is this possible programmatically? if yes, then please give me any solutions.

Comment: No , it's not possible  can you tell a use case for that

Comment: @Sh_Khan i want to navigate to another VC. in my project i'm trying that  everything is work in programatically, i don't want to use XIB And Storyboard that's why i need this i search lot but i don't get any solution for that !

Comment: If you are not using Storyboards, then you have nothing to do with view controller ID set in storyboard. Completely different tasks.

Comment: Why do you need to use a XIB or Storyboard at all then? You can just subclass UIViewController, set up your views in code, and then instantiate the class directly (i.e., `let viewController = MyViewController()`)

Comment: Sorry for being harsh but links with very little description makes for questions that help nobody else. This site is about helping everyone - and search engines have little to tag with a question like this. Particularly, what is *"ss"*? Anyways, the answer is just as vague: *"Probably not."* You see Storyboards are *meant* for Interface Builder. There *"probably is"* a way to do what you wish in code... push/pop view controllers, call a XIB from code, etc... but until you (1) give us more details, (2) give us things you've tried, (3) give us some code... it's rather hard to help you out.

Comment: @DonMag What I'm telling that i'm in FirstVC And i want to navigate to Second VC so how can i do that without interface builder ?

Comment: @dfd this storyboard navigation code it work because  i set storyboard id in interface builder                                                                                                   let formVC = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "FormViewController") as! FormViewController self.navigationController?.pushViewController(formVC, animated: true) .            if i don't want to use storyboard then it will be possible programatically or other any way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you programmtically create a VC , then you don't have to load it with identifier you only need

```
let first = FirstVC()
```

// in `AppDelegate` `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` it's suppose you use

```
self.window?.rootViewController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: first)
```

then inside the first

```
let second = SecondVC()
self.navigationcontroller?.pushViewController(second,animated:true)
```

Comment: What I'm telling that i'm in FirstVC And i want to navigate to Second VC so how can i do that without interface builder ?

Comment: if i have lot's of ViewController then it necessary to to add rootviewcontroller for that ViewController .?

Comment: the root is for the window of the app , programmatically you have to add a rootVC , as when you use storyboard the entry point vc is the root so it configured automatically